# quadratic simultaneous equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve simultaneously:

$$ 12x^2-4xy+11y^2=64 $$

$$ 16x^2-9xy+11y^2=78$$

I understand that it can be solved using the quadratic formula by rearranging the equation in $ax^2+bx+c=0 $ form
$$ (12)x^2-(4y)x+(11y^2-64)=0$$
Can this be solved using any other method (substitution or elimination?).

Comment: yes it can be solved as the intersestion points of two curves in 2d space

Comment: i.e purely geometrical solution, not algebraic

Comment: @Nikos M: This not a *method of solving*,  just a reinterpretation.  And this reformulation does not lead to any solution.

Comment: @PVanchinathan, oh realy, isnt it? Let me disagree. Of course i understand if you are used to translating everything into algebra (e.g via analytic geometry) but this is different, this is the other way around and is independent method in itself (the geometric method).It is a purely geometrical solution (which can even be implemented in computer form)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$4x^2-5xy-14=0\iff y=\dfrac{4x^2-14}{5x}$$

Replace this value of $y$ in one of the given equation form a Bi-quadratic equation in $y$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Divide one equation by the other to form an equation like $$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=0\ \ \ \ (1)$$

As $y=0\implies x^2=\dfrac{64}{12}$ and $=\dfrac{78}{16}\ne\dfrac{64}{12}$

$\implies y\ne0$

Divide $(1)$ by $y^2$ to form a Quadratic Equation in $\dfrac xy$

Solve to find $x$ in terms of $y$

Replace this value of $x$ in one of the given equation to form a Quadratic Equation in $x$